# How do I install python-virtualenv on Ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: apt, aptitude

When ever I try to `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`, I'm told that Ubuntu is unable to locate the package.

I'm running the server in a VirtualBox. It has networking and can access the web via NAT, so that's not an issue. Aptitude can see the normal Python module, but just not this particular bit that I need.

So does anyone have a way, direct or roundabout, for me to resolve this?

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a VirtualBox issue. Running the first command causes The Matrix to start running (figuratively speaking) and then after I manage to clear that, the entire UI is borked so that I can't read anything the terminal returns.

I couldn't get anything to work, so I reinstalled Ubuntu and checked to see if that resolved anything. It fixed the apt-get install so I could get it the normal way, but for thoroughness' sake I tried your command again. It once again ran The Matrix. Very strange stuff.

Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: Glad that you have solved your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it with these instructions.

```
curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz
cd virtualenv-1.10.1
sudo python setup.py install
```

If you want to know how to use it then you can visit its home page: [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)